# Warning: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r

I hope you won't downvote me for this question, i know there are a few ones asked here about the same topic but i can't understand why this happens.

I get this error message:
Warning:

```
1. In test* rep(mean(c(sec)), n) + (1 - test) * c(sec)
```

longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Now, the formula is:

```
  Sec<-  test* rep(mean(c(sec)), n) + (1 - test) * c(sec)
```

the sec takes values from a txt file.

Could you help me understand it?
Where should i look?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `test`, `rep(mean(c(sec)), n)` and `sec` are not the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax can be rewritten as

```
Sec <- test * rep(mean(sec), n) + (1 - test) * sec
```

I believe the problem is that the length of objects is not the same.

Check:

```
length(test)
n
length(sec)
```

If `n` is one, then you do not need repetition in this case. Try this code:

```
Sec <- test * mean(sec) + (1 - test) * sec
```

What are the classes of `test` and `sec`?

```
class(test)
class(sec)
```

Comment: yes, so test length is 1, and sec length is 10000, while n is 1

Comment: @Dea12 Are you sure that it is this line that is causing the warning?  If those are the object lengths,  then it shouldn't throw a warning (since 10000 is a multiple of 1).  Turn off buffered output (in R GUI, click the Misc menu and uncheck "Buffered output") and rerun your code, noting where the warning comes.

Comment: Thanks Richie, yes, thanks, it was that, i fixed it :)